# Verify button JDA with role giving

Tags: java, api, discord, discord-jda

In Java JDA using Intellij how do you create a verify button that makes it so that when you join a server you read the rules and then you press verify button and it gives you the Verified role?

Answer (score 1):

Discord natively supports something very similar called [Rules Screening](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000466882-Rules-Screening-FAQ).

> Q: I currently use a role gating through a third-party bot to have
> members agree to rules should I use this instead?
>
> A: While it is not a requirement to switch, we do believe this is a
> much more frictionless way to encourage new members to agree to rules
> and seamlessly get them in your community and participating.